# Getting XComs from cleared tasks in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I have slack alerts for when tasks fail, but I also want to have recovery messages as well.

When the task initially fails, in its `on_failure_callback` it does an `xcom_push`. What I save here is available in the next DAG run using:

```py
context['ti'].xcom_pull(key='my_task_state',
                        task_ids=context['task'].task_id,
                        include_prior_dates=True)
```

However, if I clear the failed task so that it re-runs, in its `on_failure_callback`/`on_success_callback` I try this to get the value I saved in the initial attempt:

```py
context['ti'].xcom_pull(key='my_task_state',
                        task_ids=context['task'].task_id,
                        include_prior_dates=False)
```

This returns `None`. If I set `include_prior_dates=True` it’ll return the value from the *previous* DAG run, but not the current one where the task was cleared.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a workaround that I can use to get the XCom value I’m looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yong Wang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57481879/276457) explains really well why I wasn't able to get the values I wanted. I was able to come up with a workaround however.

`xcom_push` and `xcom_pull` both just call class methods on XCom. You can call these directly. As it turns out, you can use a made up task id and it will save it to the `xcom` table under that id. Since it's not a real task, it won't be deleted when the task (nor DAG) is cleared.

```py
from airflow.models import XCom

def set_xcom(context, value):
    XCom.set(key='my_key',
             value=value
             task_id='{}_SOME_SUFFIX'.format(context['ti'].task_id),
             dag_id=context['ti'].dag_id,
             execution_date=context['ti'].execution_date)

def get_xcom(context):
    return XCom.get_one(context['ti'].execution_date,
                        key='my_key',
                        task_id='{}_SOME_SUFFIX'.format(context['ti'].task_id),
                        dag_id=context['ti'].dag_id,
                        include_prior_dates=False)
```

It's not the standard way of using XCom, so I'll just have to be careful when upgrading to a new version of Airflow in the future.

Answer (score 6):

In my understanding:

**Xcom is designed to for inter-exchange message between tasks**.
And Xcom status is **depends on the task instance**. If the task instance is cleared(delted), the xcom history info belong to this instance will be deleted as well.

That's why you get

- none when include_prior_dates=False, (task instance deleted, there is no such xcom record)
- last dag info when include_prior_dates=True,(task instance delted, but another dags tasks instance xcome was poped(most recented).

Here is show case by default example_xcom:

- 1. all_success status:

     - 1.1 dag 
       [image]
     - 1.2 the xcom list
       [image]
- 2. clear one task status:

     - 2.1 clear
       [image]
     - 2.2 the deletd xcom list
       **the xcome should be deleted**, but I failed to screen capture.

  **Thats' why your program get none.**

  - 2.3 the redo xcom list(but timestamp is different, the new record)
    [image]

if you find the answer is help, pls vote it up.  Thanks